# HTML5 input validate letters and numbers

Tags: regex, html, forms

I need a pattern for a HTML5 form.

- Lowercase letters accepted
- Uppercase letters accepted
- Numbers accepted
- Minus character accepted

**HTML so far**

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-]" required>
```

The code above does not work. I guess I'm close?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You are pretty close actually:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-]+
            ^
```

You just needed this `+` plus quantifier, which tells the input field to accept one or more the characters you have listed in the character class `[]`.

Comment: How do you tell you want at least a specific number of characters?