# Cannot get value of input field JS

Tags: javascript, html, sinatra, rack

I am very new to JS and HTML, so my apologies.
I have run into trouble trying to validate input into a form field with the pattern='' attribute. Although it catches invalid input and gives the appropriate error message, subsequent modifications of the input do not change the error message. For example,

`pattern="[a-zA-Z]"` will produce the appropriate message if the user enters "testing2" into the field. But if the user edits the entry to "testing" I still get a validation error.

In trying to figure this out, I tried to log the field input to the console.
So, in the HTML:

`<input class="dest_one_key" name="dest_one_key" type="text" id="dest_one_key" required="" placeholder="Work">`

and then:

`<script>
  var v = document.getElementById('dest_one_key').value;
  document.getElementById('dest_one_key').addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(`Value: ${v}`);
});
</script>`

...which yeilds

"Value: "

in the console. 
So the form does not seem to be capturing the users input.

What I'm doing wrong with respect to:
1) Not being able to properly register that the user has a valid input after an invalid input
2) logging the value of the field to the console?

Comment: I think what you want its something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287650/html5-input-validate-letters-and-numbers?answertab=active

Comment: Here is a simple example of it:
https://jsbin.com/natociy/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Yes! That fixed the problem with the page accepting user edits. (I searched all over the place, and this was never mentioned for the regex). Why am I running into problem 2)?

Comment: if you want to log the value you can use `keyup` event to log each time the user inputs something new. here is an example:
https://jsbin.com/natociy/4/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your script run only once, the `v` variable will be empty. You need to change it over time using `event.target.value` in your event. Like this:

```js
var v;

document.getElementById('dest_one_key').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    v = event.target.value;
    console.log('Value: ' + v);
});
```

```html
<input class="dest_one_key" name="dest_one_key" type="text" id="dest_one_key" required="" placeholder="Work">
```