# Html5 to accept only Number and characters

Tags: html

I need user to enter only numbers (0-9) and characters (a-zA-z)

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" />
```

I tried the above but this accepts a special character like `:@,#$%^&*)!` and no space in between

What I am looking for

```
Ex: Test123, 123John,
```

Comment: This regex looks fine to me--should match `Test123` and `123John` but not `123@John` or `123 John` etc.

Comment: Note that pattern verifies the input when the form is submitted. The user can type in whatever they like as they type, however, the form will give a validation error when submit is triggered.

Comment: The pattern attribute doesn't do anything until the user tries to submit. And it needs to be in a `<form>` element to work.

Comment: Good points--try adding `<form>` tags and a `<input type="submit">` button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 input validate letters and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287650/html5-input-validate-letters-and-numbers)

Comment: Not a dupe. OP already has that question/answer covered.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be wrapped in a `<form>`

```
<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required>
```

Comment: This matches a literal dash which wasn't requested by the OP.